# Google Spreadsheet: Find the largest number within a date range

Tags: excel, google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-docs

I have three columns. One has a date, one a numerical value, and the last a text value. I want to call from a different sheet the nth largest number within the last month, and then in the cell beside it, the text value corresponding with that row. The column headers are named ranges for ease, and titled Amount, Date and Name.

```
Amount  Date         Name
------  -----------  --------
5       11/11/2013   Fred
30      5/11/2013    Bob
5.2     23/11/2013   Jack
40      29/10/2013   Tim
```

If I wanted to just get biggest number, I could do "=Large(Amount;1)" which would return 40, but I'm looking to get the largest amount in the last month (not just the last 30 days) which should return 30.

What I'm currently doing to pull the name (which will give name next to the largest value, not the largest value in the last month) is "=INDEX(Name,MATCH(Large(Amount;1),Amount,0))"

All of this is being done in Google Drive on their spreadsheet.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the filter function, like this:

```
=LARGE(FILTER(A:A, YEAR(B:B) = 2013, MONTH(B:B) = 11), 1)
```

This means: get the max value from column A filtered based on the B column, where year is 2013 and month is 11.

Comment: As a follow up, I'm using: =INDEX(Name,MATCH(LARGE(FILTER(Amount, YEAR(Date) = 2013, MONTH(Date) = 11), 5),Amount,0)) to get the name of the person for the row. I'm looking at the top 5 amounts and in some cases the top two will be for the same number, but the associated names will be different. The above will use the name of the first entry for both ,0 and ,1.

Do you know how I could get the associated names?

Comment: You mean you want all the associated names in one cell? If so, you could do it like this:  
`=JOIN(", ", FILTER(C:C, A:A >= LARGE(FILTER(A:A, YEAR(B:B) = 2013, MONTH(B:B) = 11), 2), YEAR(B:B) = 2013, MONTH(B:B) = 11))`  
This joins the names associated to the 2 largest number in that month. Unfortunately, i needed to duplicate the date filtering part.

Comment: Using the QUERY function makes it a bit easier to get around the issue of ties. For example, this should return the top 5 names in that month: `=ArrayFormula(QUERY(IF({1,1,0};IF({1,0,0};Name;Amount);Date);"select Col1 where month(Col3) = 10 and year(Col3) = 2013 order by Col2 desc limit 5";0))` (note that the month() scalar function in a QUERY select clause is zero-based, ie January = 0)

Comment: AdamL, that's perfect. Thank you so much! <3

Answer (score 2):

zord's answer looks good for November 2013 but I think you want the "last month" so on December 15th assuming you want any date after November 15th then you can use a similar approach but use `EDATE` function to get a date one month back from today, i.e.

`=LARGE(FILTER(A:A,B:B>EDATE(TODAY(),-1)),1)`

Comment: This is nice because it's a "set it and forget it" sort of thing, but in this case I'm looking for the previous month. So if it's Dec 15, I want Nov1-Nov30.